# Rearranging numbers in ascending orders (Bubble sort) C++

Tags: c++, bubble-sort

sorry i'm quite new to c++ and i'm encountering some issues, please bear with me. I'm trying to make a program (i think its using something called bubble sort algorithm) that takes in the total amount of numbers, takes in all the numbers into an array and rearrange them, before displaying them. What did I do wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
int i,a[2000],temp,j,n;
cin >> n;
for(i=0;i<n;i++){ 
    cin>>a[i];
}
for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    for(j=0;j<i;j++){
        if(a[i]>a[j]){
            temp=a[i];
            a[i]=a[i-1];
            a[i-1]=temp;
        }
    }
}

for(j=0;j<n;j++){
cout<<a[j];
}
}
```

Comment: "What did I do wrong?" - It's really hard to tell if you only say what is supposed to happen, but don't show us what is actually happening

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: you need to swap a[i] with a[j], not a[i-1]

Comment: Instead of using a temp variable consider using std::swap. Also, watch out for the boundaries of your array. in the for-loops, you can potentially read a[i - 1] where i = 0, which will end up crashing your program.

Comment: @hlt im sorry I'm also not 100% aware of what is happening, but whenever i cout the numbers are not: 1. in the order i input, 2.not sorted whatsoever and 3. includes a 0 even when i did not imput 0

Comment: @NathanOliver thanks for the tip, ill definitely try it in the future!

Comment: @AlexG Thanks a lot! It works fine now, have a great day.